# Cannot upload AVI to Orchard Media

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

Hi I tried  to upload AVI video to orchard but when it's uploaded the preview video is blank, can't run the video, what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it is because browsers won't natively play avi files. You should try converting it into an mp4 or uploading to  YouTube/vimeo then embedding their player